# Filtrar EditText do listview em android

Tags: android, listview, filter

Estou fazendo este código que esta funcionando blza, mas tem um problema, na minha string tem escrito "Sr. Jose Ventura" dai quando eu digito só "jose"ou só "Ventura"não aparece nada na busca, será que alguém poderia implementar isto no meu código?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private ListView lv;
private EditText et;
private String[] lst;
private ArrayList<String> lst_Encontrados = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvlist);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlist);

    lst = new String[] {"Sr. Jose Ventura","Sra. Viviana Araujo","Sr. Mario Jorge"};

    //Carrega o listview com todos os itens
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst));
    CarregarEncontrados();

    //Adiciona um TextWatcher ao TextView cujos métodos são chamados sempre
    //que este TextView sofra alterações.
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
        {
            // Abstract Method of TextWatcher Interface.
        }

        //Evento acionado quando o usuário teclar algo
        //na caixa de texto "Procurar"
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            CarregarEncontrados();

            //Carrega o listview com os itens encontrados
            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst_Encontrados));
        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {


            AlertDialog.Builder test = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

            if(((TextView) view).getText().equals("Sr. Jose Ventura")){
                test.setTitle("Doido");
                test.setMessage("doidera");
                test.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                test.show();


            }
            if(((TextView) view).getText().equals("Sr. Mario Jorge")){
                test.setTitle("Vizinho");
                test.setMessage("kct");
                test.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                test.show();
            }

            if(((TextView) view).getText().equals("Sra. Viviana Araujo")){
                test.setTitle("eu");
                test.setMessage("louquinha");
                test.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                test.show();;;
            }


        }
    });



}


public void CarregarEncontrados() {
    int textlength = et.getText().length();

    lst_Encontrados.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < lst.length; i++) {
        if (textlength <= lst[i].length()) {

            String textoAux = (String) lst[i].subSequence(0, textlength);
            String textoFormatado = et.getText().toString();

            //Removendo acentos do item da lista a comparar
            textoAux = removeAcentos(textoAux);
            //Removendo acentos do item digitado
            textoFormatado = removeAcentos(textoFormatado);
            if (textoFormatado.equalsIgnoreCase(textoAux)) {
                lst_Encontrados.add(lst[i]);

            }
        }
    }
}
private static Map<Character, Character> acentosMap;

public static String removeAcentos(String texto) {

    if (acentosMap == null || acentosMap.size() == 0) {
        acentosMap = new HashMap<>();
        acentosMap.put('À', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('Á', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('Â', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('Ã', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('Ä', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('È', 'E');
        acentosMap.put('É', 'E');
        acentosMap.put('Ê', 'E');
        acentosMap.put('Ë', 'E');
        acentosMap.put('Í', 'I');
        acentosMap.put('Ì', 'I');
        acentosMap.put('Î', 'I');
        acentosMap.put('Ï', 'I');
        acentosMap.put('Ù', 'U');
        acentosMap.put('Ú', 'U');
        acentosMap.put('Û', 'U');
        acentosMap.put('Ü', 'U');
        acentosMap.put('Ò', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Ó', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Ô', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Õ', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Ö', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('Ñ', 'N');
        acentosMap.put('Ç', 'C');
        acentosMap.put('ª', 'A');
        acentosMap.put('º', 'O');
        acentosMap.put('§', 'S');
        acentosMap.put('³', '3');
        acentosMap.put('²', '2');
        acentosMap.put('¹', '1');
        acentosMap.put('à', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('á', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('â', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('ã', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('ä', 'a');
        acentosMap.put('è', 'e');
        acentosMap.put('é', 'e');
        acentosMap.put('ê', 'e');
        acentosMap.put('ë', 'e');
        acentosMap.put('í', 'i');
        acentosMap.put('ì', 'i');
        acentosMap.put('î', 'i');
        acentosMap.put('ï', 'i');
        acentosMap.put('ù', 'u');
        acentosMap.put('ú', 'u');
        acentosMap.put('û', 'u');
        acentosMap.put('ü', 'u');
        acentosMap.put('ò', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('ó', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('ô', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('õ', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('ö', 'o');
        acentosMap.put('ñ', 'n');
        acentosMap.put('ç', 'c');
    }

    if (texto == null) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(texto);

    for (int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++) {
        Character c = acentosMap.get(sb.charAt(i));
        if (c != null) {
            sb.setCharAt(i, c);
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: Sim wellingto Avelino, decido apenas mudar o tema da pergunta e colocar o codigo completo, pois não consegui implementar sua respota, que creio ser muito efeciente mas complexa para mim.

Comment: Recomendo Editar sua pergunta nesses casos @wilfer

Comment: ah, valeu @WellingtonAvelino!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nessa parte sua do código: 
`lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst));` 
fica melhor usar uma variável e usar o método getfilter do ArrayAdapter, fazendo essa alteração seu código ficaria assim:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lst_Encontrados);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

E no método addTextChangedListener você manipula os resultados a partir do adapter e não do ListView e colocando o adapter de forma inline seria impossível usar ele dessa forma:

```
 et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                      int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                  int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0.toString());
            }
            if (arg0.toString().equals("")) {
                adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    });
```

Dessa forma não é necessário fazer o filtro usando o seu método criado, usando apenas uma função do próprio ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Amigao tentei aqui, digitei igual a voce digitou, nem sequer copiei e colei hahaha, ve so agora nao busca mais as palavras o resto funciona, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: dei uma editada na resposta, dessa forma você poderá fazer a busca de após os espaços, mas não será possível buscar dentro de uma palavra, por exemplo: "ose", ou "entura", e sempre que seu edit text ficar em branco, ele retornará a lista na forma original